# powershell script to add certificate

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I wish to add a certificate in central admin using PowerShell script. I have no experience at all with PowerShell. I got this script somewhere from other site but not sure if it's correct or not.

```
Remove-SPTrustedRootAuthority CASigningRootCert
Remove-SPTrustedRootAuthority CASigningCert
$rootcert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2("full_path_to_updated_certificate_authority_certificate.cer")
$cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2("full_path_to_signing_certificate.cer")
$tip = Get-SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer name_of_trusted_identity_provider   
$tip.SigningCertificate = $cert
$tip.Update()
New-SPTrustedRootAuthority -Name "CASigningRootCert" -Certificate $rootcert
New-SPTrustedRootAuthority -Name "CASigningCert" -Certificate $cert
```

From above should i replace ?`Full_path_to_updated_certificate_authority_certificate.cer` with certificate which i have

What should I replace this with?`Full_path_to_signing_certificate.cer`

What should i replace this with `name_of_trusted_identity_provider`

If above script is not correct then is there any simple script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add the certificate to the Central Admin trust is easy. You have to run the below command for each certificate.

```
$cert = Get-PfxCertificate c:\CsAppTier.cer
New-SPTrustedRootAuthority -Certificate $cert -Name CsAppTier
```

- c:\CsAppTier.cer is path & name of the certificate which you want
  an import.
- -Name CsAppTier, You can name whatever you want or type of cert it is.

The code you mentioned is related to ADFS configuration.

Comment: so i replace -Name CsAppTier like mycer.cer ?

Comment: with full path, i.e. path\mycer.cer

Comment: but on sharepoint server which path i should select? any path?

Comment: What is location of certificate? you should save the certificate on the server where you want to run the command

Comment: But on any location, on the server

Comment: so is this correct New-SPTrustedRootAuthority -Certificate $cert -"c:\mycer.cer"

Comment: you have to run the first command first then 2nd

Comment: $cert = Get-PfxCertificate c:\mycer.cer

Comment: New-SPTrustedRootAuthority -Certificate $cert -Name NameofCert